# copy files from one drive on a site to another one drive on different site on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Here is my main problem.
I have a file on one drive at https://-my.sharepoint.com/personal/ and I would like to copy this file to https://-my.sharepoint.com/personal/ using a sharepoint hosted app.

I have gone through the REST API and tried the copyTo request but I think that only allows files to copy in the same one drive.

I have also gone through Michael Svenson's blog on how to copy files between sites but was unsuccessul. [Here](http://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html) is the link:

Is there any way to do the above using REST API or JSOM on sharepoint hosted app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My bad.....here is what i want to do.....copy File from https://-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user1 to https://-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user2.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find the solution. For those who are trying to do the same please follow the below steps and it should work for you guys.

First follow all the steps that Michael Svenson's blog provides.

Once you get the data.body execute the following with same `SP.RequestExeutor` object.

```
<p>var url = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/personal/someUser_domain_com/Documents')/Files/Add(url='test.docx', overwrite=true)?@target='" + userTargetUrl + "'";</p>

<p>var info = {
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            binaryStringRequestBody: true,
            body: data.body,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success! Your file was uploaded to SharePoint.");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Oooooops... it looks like something went wrong uploading your file.");
            }
        };
        executor.executeAsync(info);
    }</p>
```